# DELETE Runs Longer than SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

The DELETE query below runs way longer than the very same SELECT statement. For comparison, the SELECT query runs for 1 minute and the DELETE query runs for over 5 minutes and actually times out. Why does this happen and how can I prevent this?

**SELECT QUERY (1 MINUTE)**

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    company
WHERE
    symbol IN (SELECT 
            `hd`.`symbol` AS `symbol`
        FROM
            (`stockton`.`historical_data` `hd`
            JOIN (SELECT 
                MAX(`stockton`.`historical_data`.`histDate`) AS `maxhd`
            FROM
                `stockton`.`historical_data`) `m`)
        GROUP BY `hd`.`symbol` , `m`.`maxhd`
        HAVING (MAX(`hd`.`histDate`) < (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)));
```

**DELETE QUERY (5+ MINUTES)**

```
DELETE
FROM
    company
WHERE
    symbol IN (SELECT 
            `hd`.`symbol` AS `symbol`
        FROM
            (`stockton`.`historical_data` `hd`
            JOIN (SELECT 
                MAX(`stockton`.`historical_data`.`histDate`) AS `maxhd`
            FROM
                `stockton`.`historical_data`) `m`)
        GROUP BY `hd`.`symbol` , `m`.`maxhd`
        HAVING (MAX(`hd`.`histDate`) < (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)));
```

Comment: There could be a lot of reasons that the `DELETE` takes so much longer and without knowing a lot of details about your system it would be difficult to figure out why. For starters though, a `DELETE` actually needs to update data on disk, rearrange indexes, etc. It will basically always be more expensive than a `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Improvement: You may want to change your query to calculate `Date = Now - 7 days` in your programming language instead of calculating in query itself.

Delete taking more time: Delete generally will take more time and if you will google you will find out that you're not alone. Reason being that Delete is an expensive operation compared to Select because Delete requires following:
1) Compare the record with your condition
2) Delete from table
3) Remove references from one or more indexes created on the table
4) may or may not update table's meta-data depending on the engine

while Select is:
1) Compare the record with your condition or if condition is using Index then use the index
2) Return the resulted value

Considering that you have larger table, you might have larger indexes and it will take time in manipulation compared to just select.

But you can try suggested improvement and should see some improvements in time.